# Why does YouTube keep buffering video playback on a high speed connection on a Lenovo IdeaPad 320-15ISK running Windows 11 Pro?

Tags: windows, windows-11, lenovo-laptop, youtube, buffer

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 320-15ISK with Core i5 7th Gen, 8 GB RAM, and 128 GB SSD running Windows 11 Pro. Playing a video on YouTube keeps buffering yet my internet speed is around 50Mbps.

This issue happens only on my laptop, others are okay. Sometimes the WiFi connection disconnects randomly and reconnects only when playing a YouTube video.

What might be the issue?

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem: you state, "Sometimes the WiFi connection disconnects," but the title is about a YouTube issue. If the WiFi is unstable, don't expect an application *using* WiFi would be.

Comment: Brand/Model, CPU, RAM and storage space are of little to none relevance for the reported problem. Please [edit] the question and add relevant specifications like the actual WiFi device it has and driver version.